# Is it possible to send an ouput stream as response to a HTTP request?

Tags: java, http, httprequest, outputstream

Consider the case where Server B makes a HTTP request to Server A (Which is an encryption server) and get an output stream (which is encrypted). So that Server B could write with the help of this encrypted stream.

Now this encrypted output stream would be opened in Server A and closed at Server B.

1. Is it possible to send an output stream in HTTP response?
2. Is it a right way to send an output stream in response? Or are there any conventions like the output stream must be closed in the same server (or same application) where it is originated?

Comment: You don't "send" an output stream. A server writes bytes to its HTTP response output stream, so that the client can receive the bytes in its connection's input stream. An Output stream is like a keyboard: you use it to write things. An InputStream is like a screen: you use it to read things. But you don't send a keyboard to someone to say something. You type it on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot JB Nizet :) Though we have variables (of different data types) to read/write data in memory then why do we go for streams? Please help me know this.

Comment: A stream is rarely used to write things in memory. It's mainly used to write things to the disk, or to the network. If you have two servers, even on the same machine, they don't share the same memory. A variable stored in one process is not accessible from the other process. So you need to communicate between them by sending messages over the network. To continue with metaphors: you can write a note on a post-it for your wife who lives in your house. But to tell something to me, you need to send messages over the network.

Comment: Wow !! Very nice Explanation JB Nizet. Very much satisfied :) 

But I still need a few clarifications 
1. Is there any other thing similar to stream for communication over a network?
2. Have you refered to the http request and response as a network here?

Then coming to my initial post - we cannot create an encrypted output stream at Server B(which is for reading and writing the data) since it has to be done only in Server A (which is meant for encryption - which would provide me an encrypted output stream for writing). So will it be any other way around. Kindly help me.

Comment: http is a network protocol. It consists in a client sending a request, over the network, to a server, and the server responding to that request with a response, over the network. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. But I have the feeling it's much too complex for the skills you have now. Start by learning the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. That's how the file download works.

First you'll have to set the `Content-Type` that you're going to provide. If it's simple binary file then set it as `application/octet-stream`. After that get `outputStream` of the response and dump the file content in it.

Like below

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength(fileSizeInBytes);//new File('myfile').length(), optional step
response.getOutputStream().write(fileBytes);//do it in chunks
```

**#Edit**

Streams are endpoints of data channels. Like an HTTP address is an endpoint to the server resource.

In case of stream our program doesn't need to know where the actual resource resides. I just need to know how to interact with the stream.

So in case of `HttpServletResponse` stream, data lies in your server. Client's browser (or any other client) establishes a connection with your server. When we call methods on the stream like read/write, data over this connection is sent or received. These calls in case of `HttpServletResponse` result in HTTP packet transfer over TCP connection.

For more information on Java Stream (or any other language with similar concept) check here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Comment: Thanks a lot 11thdimension. I couldn't visualize how outputStream works..

I understand in the way that it is similar to a pointer variable in C pointing to an address and would write data to it if we call .write() method. 

Please correct me if am wrong. And please help me get a clear idea about Streams.

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Thanks again 11thdimensionion :) I still like to clarify these..
1. We have Strings - we read get data from string and store data in string like wise other data types for read/write data in memory

Then why do we come for streams? What is the necessary to create streams? Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Stream is an abstraction over any type of binary/text data. This abstraction hides how the data is being produced or consumed. We don't have to know if we are reading data from a Socket, File in file system, a Byte array etc. You can think of it as a standard API to interact with data. Like JDBC API provides abstraction over many types of relation data bases.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I realised this few years post that.